# How to Disable File Verification while installing Cyanogen in Nexus One

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-one, recovery-mode

When I try to install CyanogenMod through ClockworkMod Recovery process I get the following error, ‘failed to verify whole-file signature’.

I followed [WikiLink for Cyanogen](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php/Full_Update_Guide_-_Nexus_One_Firmware_to_CyanogenMod#Flashing_CyanogenMod) for carrying out the installation.

Is there any way to disable file verification or any other way through which I can overcome this error.

I am using Nexus One phone with,

```
Kernel Version   - 2.6.35.7. 
Build number     - GRK39F. 
Android version - 2.3.6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In current versions of Clockworkmod Recovery, go into the "Install zip from sdcard" menu and chose "toggle signature verification".

---

Previous answer:

You're in stock recovery, not CWM recovery.  CWM recovery doesn't verify signatures.  You either failed to install the recovery properly, or you need to hit "install packages" or similar from the stock recovery in order to get into CWM.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But I downloaded CWM Recovery from the wiki link I pointed, used fastboot  and got Success message. 
I am new to this (rooting and stuffs). so can you please tell in detail how can I install CWM. Any link where I can find instructions for Nexus One.

Comment: Just to double check, your recovery screen should look something like this if your using ClockworkMod Recovery. http://bit.ly/wAFUBb

Comment: @SyncMaster Could be that the recovery is being overwritten, so make sure you go directly to recovery after flashing it (without a full reboot) so that it can't be overwritten.  Also try hitting "install packages" from the stock recovery, I have to do that on my Vibrant to get CWM installed at least.